# Python method to append list not working?

Tags: python-2.7, class

I'm trying to work with classes right now in Python. I've created objects from a class:

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.b = bar
    def assignbar(self, somelist):
        self.b.extend(somelist)
foo1=foo2=foo3=Class1([])
```

At this point, printing foo1.b, foo2.b, and foo3.b does, in fact, give empty lists.
Now, I have a separate list that is, say, 15 elements long. The following is where I have my problem:

```
numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
foo1.assignbar(numbers[0:5])
foo2.assignbar(numbers[5:10])
foo3.assignbar(numbers[10:15])
print foo1.b
print foo2.b
print foo3.b
```

Instead of giving me [0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9], and [10,11,12,13,14], this simply gives me the entirety of numbers three times. However, when I define foo1, foo2, and foo3 separately like this:

```
foo1=Class1([])
foo2=Class1([])
foo3=Class1([])
```

the program runs as I think it should. I would like to know, why is it that setting all 3 objects as the same thing doesn't work. Is it because when you call assignbar on any one of them, it calls assignbar on all of the other three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example:

```
foo1=foo2=foo3=Class1([])
```

You're only creating a single instance of `Class1`, and assigning it three different names. Whether you perform a method on `foo1`, `foo2`, or `foo3`, it's acting on the same instance. Note that you would get the same result from the following:

```
foo3 = Class1([])
foo2 = foo3
foo1 = foo3
```

Your second example properly instantiates the class three times, and thus works as you expect.

Note that this isn't specific to user-defined classes, but to any mutable object:

```
>>> foo1 = foo2 = foo3 = []
>>> foo1.append(1)
>>> foo1
[1]
>>> foo2
[1]
>>> foo3
[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing the problem is because you're working in the same instances. the firts time the object foo1 get the list [0,1,2,3,4] and all the other object the get same value. After the object foo2[5,6,7,8,9] and all the objects get the same value. I thing I thing it should be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `foo1=foo2=foo3=Class1([])`, `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` are referring to exact same object(instance), which means whatever you do to any of them, the exact same object will be modified, it just has three names(`foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`) for you to use.

```
foo1=Class1([])
foo2=Class1([])
foo3=Class1([])
```

While in above codes, `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` are three different instances of `Class1`, they are not referring to same object.

You can always use `id(foo1)`, `id(foo2)` or `id(foo3)` to find out if they are exactly the same or not.